# React-Native:Not able to send props from ListView

Tags: listview, react-native

I made a listView using redux and axios request and everything seems fine....but i can't get the object in my render method...

Here is my code

```
   import React from 'react';
import { View, ListView, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ItemOverView } from '../../components/common';
import * as actions from '../../actions';

class AwaitingScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
  header: null,
  };

  state = { loading: true };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getAwaitingOrders();
    this.createDataSource(this.props);
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ loading: false });
    this.createDataSource(nextProps);
  }
  createDataSource(orders) {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });
    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(orders);
  }

  renderListView() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (<ActivityIndicator
        size='large'
        color='#397af8'
      />
    );
    }
    return (
      <ListView
        enableEmptySections
        dataSource={this.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
      />
    );
  }
  renderRow = (order) => {
    return (
      <ItemOverView
        item={order}
      />
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.renderListView()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    awaitingOrders: state.orders.awaitingOrders,
    statusCodes: state.orders.statusCodes
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(AwaitingScreen);
```

ITEMVIEW:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

 class ItemOverView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.item);

    return (
      <View style={style.containerStyle}>
        <Text>{this.props.item.id}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const style = {
  containerStyle: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 1,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginTop: 10,
  }
};
export { ItemOverView };
```

As i run this code,I get an error 
**undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.item.id')**...The json i receive has 6 items in it and I get it correctly(checked from console.log).If i pass something static to ItemView...say item = 'product' then it gets rendered 6 times...so everything seems to works well, But for some reason it won't get the object

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't use propTypes. In RN if you import your component from outside and send your data in to it, you can use propTypes.

You can install with npm.

```
npm install --save prop-types
```

And after, here try this ITEMVIEW, it should work. If not, this means problem is in your data. So, check your data before calling your component.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

 class ItemOverView extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.item);

    return (
      <View style={style.containerStyle}>
        <Text>{this.props.item.id}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const style = {
  containerStyle: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 1,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginTop: 10,
  }
};
ItemOverView.propTypes = {
  item: PropTypes.object,
};
ItemOverView.defaultProps = {
  item: null,
};
export { ItemOverView };
```